# Explanation of numpy's Chebyshev curve fit

Tags: least-squares, chebyshev-polynomials

I'm writing a mini-library in C++ to find a 4th order Chebyshev polynomial (of the first kind) curve fit on set of x/y points varying in size (between 5-36 sets of points).

I have found a pretty good example in Python's numpy library in the numpy.polynomial.chebyshev module.  See function 'chebfit' [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/chebyshev.py).

I'm trying to find a paper or explanation of this method as the library is a bit brief and utilizes a lot of innate features of python that are difficult to convert to C++.  [This](http://www.math.niu.edu/~dattab/MATH435.2013/APPROXIMATION.pdf) is the closest I've come to an explanation of the chebyshev.py methodology, however, there's a lot of extra stuff that's making it tricky for me to follow.

Does anybody know a better resource for following the numpy library least squares methodology, or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to figure out how it works or do you just just need to write one in c++?

Comment: I am not sure what it is supposed to do, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html  $\leftarrow$ is it supposed to fit all $T_0,\cdots,T_4$ or just find the best coefficient for a lone $T_4$?

Comment: @mathreadler, I just need to write it, although usually it helps to understand it when you're writing it.  I do need all 5 coefficients.  I guess my most basic question, is the link I tagged actually following the same methodology as the numpy library?  They both start with a vandermode matrix and then move to a least squares methodology, but after that I'm lost and not sure they're the same.  If I'm going to convert code from one language to another, I at least need a guide that explains the steps and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, ehm, you can make a matrix of the coefficients, and a vector of the x:s, then you compute the values for each polynomial ($T_k(x)$) at each points ($x$) and each of the degrees ($k$), build a matrix from it. Then you want to find which linear combinations of these $T_k$ to fit you $y$ vector. This is where the least squares fitting comes into plays. I can write an answer for you but I am a bit distracted and also running out of battery at the moment.

Comment: No hurry. I actually got that far and the least squares is where numpy library was difficult to follow (takes advantage of a lot of python functionality I'm not familiar with).  No hurry on an answer, I'm going to study it myself the next few days, I was just searching for the right reference to study.

Comment: Ok so you understand everything up to the linear solver. I am sure there are linear algebra libraries for c++ if you don't want to implement a solver for yourself. For example the Boost c++ libraries should be quite extensive nowadays. They even were quite good some 8 years ago.

Comment: But you would probably want to add some Tikhonov regularizing term too as polynomial fitting often can give very unreasonable behaviour between points. So switch to solve the normal equations instead and add $+\epsilon {\bf I}$